# How to compute the Value-at-Risk of an equity portfolio hedged using futures contracts?

Tags: futures, value-at-risk, models

I would like to have your opinions about how to calculate the VaR of a hedged portfolio using futures contracts.

I have tried several "black box" softwares and none of them make too much sense. The idea is that I have a 100% Equity Portfolio and a 100% coverage with futures that might no be very well correlated to the Portfolio itself. How would you calculate the VaR? With what model?

Comment: Couldn't you just simulate the daily performance over a past historical period and take the 95-th percentile?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main methods for VaR Calculation: Historical, Parametric and Monte Carlo ([see here](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/092904.asp)). All 3 can be performed on simple softwares like Excel or Matlab.

Parametric and Monte Carlo requires a few assumptions including return distribution on equity, futures and rates.

A Simple parametric VaR and Historical VaR can be done in one small page of spreadsheet, really.

I will present an example on **Historical VaR**, as I'm most familiar with.

1. Choose number of windows. For example, 250 cases (1 year)

   *VaR of today position (t) is based on historical data*
2. collect historical return of equity and return of futures on t-1
3. apply that return of equity on t-1 to today equity position and return of futures on t-1 to today futures position  and record dollar P&L
4. repeat 2-3 but change t-1 to t-2
5. do 4 (by changing t-2 to t-3 and so on) until you have 250 cases
6. Choose your significance level, say 5%
7. Rank those 250 P&L and get 5%th lowest percentile (top 5% most negative P&L)

This method doesn't require assumption on return distributions or correlation of equity and futures.

It, though, assumes that past characteristic and relationship will keep continuing in the future.

Comment: I also assume 250 points are enough to estimate what's in the tails of the distribution.